# Is there any method to avoid Bankers rounding in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example
`round(18.5)` gives me 18
`round(19.5)` gives me 20
I want the output of `round(18.5)` to be `19`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`math.floor(x + 0.5)` will always round `.5` up.

Comment: um, what's the $x? It says SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Sorry, was thinking PHP

Comment: Oh, I see. and by the way, you have to define x first if you are going to execute this code

Comment: Yes, I was trying to give an answer that would work for something other than just 18.5.